# recurrence relation for tree

Tags: algorithm

suppose there is a tree with number of child nodes increasing from 2 to 4 then 8 and so on.how can we write recurrence relation for such a tree.

Answer (score 1):

- using subtitution method- T(n)=2T(n/2)+n
     =2[2T(n/2^2)+n/2]+n
     =2^2T(n/2^2)+n+n
     =2^2[2T(n/2^3)+n/2^2]+n+n
     =2^3T(n/2^3)+n+n+n

  similarly subtituing k times--  we get

  T(n)=2^k T(n/2^k)+nk
     the recursion will terminate when n/2^k=1
                                   k=log n  base 2.

  thus T(n)=2^log n(base2)+n(log n)
          =n+nlogn

  thus the tight bound for the above recurrence relation will be 
          =n log N (base of log is 2)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/recurrence.html).

```
T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + O(n)         [the O(n) is for Combine]
T(1) = O(1)
```

Comment: i am looking for recurrence relation of a tree which has varying number of childs per node.this number of nodes is varying according to the height of node.